# How can I mock Bun global object with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, bun

I'm using Bun + TS + jest.

Right now I'm writing my tests and I need to mock Bun.file.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "moduleDetection": "force",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "composite": true,
        "strict": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "types": [
            "bun-types", // add Bun global
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.json", "src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

This is how my jest.config.cjs looks like

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "node",
    globals: {
        "ts-jest": {
            Bun: true,
        },
    },
};
```

this is how my test looks like

```
import {
    expect,
    describe,
    test,
    beforeAll,
    beforeEach,
    jest,
} from "@jest/globals";
import TasksFacade from "../../src/facades/TasksFacade";
import { TasksFacadeConfig } from "../../src/common/types";

let facade: TasksFacade;
let facadeConfig: TasksFacadeConfig;

beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.Bun, "file").mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            ...global.Bun.file,
            exists: () => Promise.resolve(true),
            json: () => Promise.resolve([]),
        };
    });
});

beforeEach(() => {
    facadeConfig = {
        tasksSource: "Local",
        cmsEnv: ["localhost"],
        pagesToCapture: [
            {
                url: "/",
                pageName: "Index",
                renderers: {
                    desktop: {
                        width: 1400,
                        height: 500,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    };
});

describe("TasksFacade", () => {
    test("Should call Bun.file with the correct path", async () => {
        facade = new TasksFacade(facadeConfig);

        await facade.getSitesLocal();

        expect(global.Bun.file).toHaveBeenCalledWith("tasks.json", {
            type: "application/json",
        });
    });
});
```

and this is how the function that is using Bun looks like

```
   async getSitesLocal(): Promise<SiteData[]> {
        const sitesFile = Bun.file(path.resolve(currDir, "..", "sites.json"), {
            type: "application/json",
        });
        if (await sitesFile.exists()) {
            const rawSites = await sitesFile.json();
            return rawSitesToSiteData(rawSites);
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

this is the error that I'm getting

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '() => { exists: () => Promise<boolean>; json: () => Promise<never[]>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(fileDescriptor: number, options?: BlobPropertyBag | undefined) => BunFile'.
      Type '{ exists: () => Promise<boolean>; json: () => Promise<never[]>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'BunFile': slice, writer, readable, lastModified, and 7 more.

    16     jest.spyOn(global.Bun, "file").mockImplementation(() => {
                                                             ~~~~~~~
```

seems that I'm missing some properties and TS is not happy with that, but I don't know how to comply with what TS is requiring me.

I tried jest.spyon along jest mock implementation to mock Bun file, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to remove the `...global.Bun.file,` as that line seems to be destructuring the `Bun.file` function, rather than the return values.

Assuming the only things you'd want from the response is `json` and `exists`, one option would be to cast the type so that the return type is a [Bunfile](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/blob/98d19fa6244384f7e17998b5420d724481ed3835/packages/bun-types/bun.d.ts#L2463):

```
beforeAll(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.Bun, "file").mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            exists: () => Promise.resolve(true),
            json: () => Promise.resolve([]),
        } as unknown as BunFile;
    });
});
```